# How to make a method argument optional or required based on a generic type

Tags: typescript, class

I've an `EventEmitter` class with `register` and `emit` methods and with generic Type for which the event emitter will deal with, and I want both these secnarios

If a Type is specified when creating object from the class, we want both the register and emit args to be required. Like

```
const emitter1 = new EventEmitter<number>();
emitter1.register((value) => {
  console.log("Received:", value);
})();
emitter1.emit(43);
```

But if type is not specified, we want args for emit method optional, since I want only to trigger the emitter regardless of the value, like

```
const emitter2 = new EventEmitter();
emitter2.register(() => {
  console.log("Received (optional):");
})();
emitter2.emit();
```

But I'm confused on how to make the emit argument to be optional if type is not specified, and required if type is specified.

I've attached the code below, thanks.

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgogNwgO2HAtgS2MCAnAYQEMAbEgIyIGMBrAHhnAgD4oBeWJqCAD12QAmAZygBXQRABmmZBAFQA-FAAUVUhWo0AaqVEQFALihFkIAJTtWCAPaZ5R1esq0dJPUcaQLbK7YEAofyoSIiERRBQ0LBx8Bi4OcQEpGTlWAG9-biRUABlMIX58ISMAQTw8IhAGCNQMbFxCJ004yGZmAG5AqCprZAK8USpgazxlCwyoSeAAC3yAOghs4DyClCL2KABtAF1OqABfLoB6I9hZkV6SEChgIhoIC9ljPABzUXRI40EoAHdodDu0BmRGAzzeH1QUGsYGAmF6pCglCEcihyBu0yBXGsknR0GCoSEmTwEBe%20QajjIzhoHhqUXq%20GIlOanhYZgc3l8digE3R80WkRWhTwQjmYFEQmmFI0tDMe0mxOAojwaLGlm5mUmkx6fVBaiZtAAkhIeBsZnyloK1sK5jIkjwAPKSKVU2UazWYHHOzRGu1QVgAWgAjOM3ZreSL%20bkyVaRUIwCRMFQIF7DcaADRQYNyzWHHN7Q6ZE5nfKoq43QGPaBEV7vT4meR-KAA%207okFg2uQ6Gw%20EkRGhFG9XE3LE4mZ4kJhTIQaLKBC6CBmCZmiMW6Oya2SEZwaiSlM0Dnq7pNWiz%20eug7nw4FotwHhEdDx6DiogvCAGIK9ArcaINQMbWQ-FAtJ1DEeB0Mg7zkPgzBjJ0070nggZzMSpKrKMp5uAuao8tqQjWCQEBzCQ1gvMoABEABKEBJpgSACAYZEZnOmGuvsZiwf48GgUhXHKAALAAzK6H46t%20CEAEz-hAgHAT%20%20AcVxDTichJLRuhB44Z%20%20GEcRpGUdREC0SiyhdnCyCkGyZGsexrqKfgym8bKQA)

Comment: Use another conditional https://tsplay.dev/wjeK2W

Comment: cool, but there's one ts-ignore

Comment: Well, I'd suggest using a type assertion instead of ts-ignore, but you'll need to do  *something* to loosen type safety because the compiler will never understand this sort of generic conditional stuff.  Does that fully address the question? If so then maybe @kelsny will write up an answer.  If not, what's missing?

Comment: yes, it make sense, it would be better  also to post the type assertion as well without ts-ignore. thanks